# how do you add webpack configuration to the karma config generated by the cli?

Tags: angular, webpack, jasmine

I am trying to expose a global variable on the window object that can set in my test entry point and be available in all of my individual spec files.

Some have suggested to me that I do:

```
interface Window { myGlobalFunc: (x: any) => void; } window.myGlobalFunc = function(x) {...};
```

However when I do that, I get compile errors: `error TS2304: Cannot find name 'myGlobalFunc'.`

Others suggested using the `Output Library Type` in the webpack config, however the karma config generated by the angular CLI does not have a webpack config defined.  I tried adding the karma-webpack plugin (https://github.com/ryanclark/karma-webpack) however as soon as I give it a webpack config, I get: `Server start failed on port 9876: TypeError: Cannot read property 'outputPath' of undefined`.  I tried opening an [issue](https://github.com/ryanclark/karma-webpack/issues/519) with the karma-webpack, but no one has responded.

How can I expose a global function available in all my spec files?

Answer (score 1):

This might not answer your question and I am not an expert in Webpack.

To get a function attached to the `window` object, I would do:

test.ts, define it here in the entry point of where the tests run

```
...
(window as any).myGlobalFunc = () => console.log('Hello World!');
// Then we find all the tests.
const context = require.context('./', true, /\.spec\.ts$/);
...
```

And then in my `.spec.ts` file, I would use it:

```
(window as any).myGlobalFunc();
```

It's not pretty, but it should work

Edit (create a re-usable function not attached to the window object):

func.ts

```
export const sayHello = () => console.log('Hello world!');
```

To use it:
*.spec.ts

```
import { sayHello } from './where/func.ts/is';
....
sayHello();
```

Comment: Hmmm...  I am trying to just be able to call `myGlobalFunc();` from my test files.  There has to be a way to do this..  Jasmine does this as I can call `describe()`, `it()`, `beforeEach()`, etc without having to do `(window as any).beforeEach()`

Comment: You get access to `describe, it, beforeEach` from `@types/jasmine` I believe and `tsconfig.spec.json` includes these types in a types array I believe. Does the function have to be attached to the window object? If not, you can export the function and import it in any test that requires it and call it there. Check out my edit.

Comment: yeah, I am trying to actually alias `it()`, so I was hoping to be able to have access to it in all spec files without having to import it.  But if that's really the only way to get what I am looking for, then I guess I will go with the import option..  Just seems so annoying.

Comment: If you use Visual Studio Code as your text editor, you can just type the beginning characters of the method/function name and it will auto complete/give some suggestions and you can pick from the list. Once selected, it will auto import the function. Usually the first one is correct. This is one of the reasons why I love TypeScript and VS Code.